# How long a livy session is maintained in head node memory?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, livy

Once a job is posted to livy, it creates a session for it. Then spark-submit, submits the job to yarn and yarn then executes the job. Till what point the session is maintained by livy in memory? Till submission to yarn or till it's execution is completed by yarn?

Answer (score 2):

Basically it dependes on the setting you passed.

inactive session will be stopped after `livy.server.session.timeout`

see these properties to set in livy.conf

```
# Enabled to check whether timeout Livy sessions should be stopped.
# livy.server.session.timeout-check = true

# Time in milliseconds on how long Livy will wait before timing out an idle session.
# livy.server.session.timeout = 1h
#
# How long a finished session state should be kept in LivyServer for query.
# livy.server.session.state-retain.sec = 600s
```